# Hot Reload is working, but a refresh (⌘+R) leads to blank/white screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a (at least for me) weird problem with my current react-native project setup (it's actually a PoC but the plan is to use this structure in the future).

My structure (excerpt):

```
.
├── BaseApp
├── foobar
└── foobar2
```

Inside of my app I added the local modules via `yarn add ../foobar` and `yarn add ../foobar2` (it's planned to use yarn-workspaces or callstack/haul in the future project setup). Both modules provide a react-native module with a simple native part.

I import the modules inside my App:

```ts
import Foobar from 'foobar';
import Foobar2 from 'foobar2';
```

And use them in the component:

```tsx
const [status, setStatus] = useState('Init ...');
const [message, setMessage] = useState('---');
const [multiply, setMultiply] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    Foobar2.sampleMethod('Testing', 123, (message: string) => {
        setStatus('Received...');
        setMessage(message);
    });
    Foobar.multiply(3, 7).then(setMultiply);
}, []);

// ...

<Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>Status: {status}</Text>
<Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>Message: {message}</Text>
<Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>Result: {multiply}</Text>
```

Initially the app loads and stays white/blank. No error. No hint about whats probably going wrong. When I remove the imports and reload (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+r or type `r` in the console) the app reloads and shows an error about the (indeed) missing variables:
[image: Error after reload]

If I add the imports again, the app reloads via hot reload (HMR) and voila, it works ...
[image: Works after HMR]

Why? I can't explain it to myself why this is happen. Maybe someone can help me to understand that which might help me to fix that "weird" behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem. In my case, I had `react-native` as a dev dependency in one of my local modules. As a result, there were 2 instances of the react-native runtime which leads to 3 different "Invariant Violation"-Errors. The problem: I saw this error first after I attached a debugger to the app. This makes it very hard to find such (simple) errors and is very disappointing :/

I hope it helps someone else if you got the same behavior without any errors printed out.